# how do you show ModalBottomSheet automatically?

Tags: flutter, dart

[how do I display _showModalBottomSheet ???](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ETEF.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling your `_showModalBottomSheet` method, so replace

```
_showModalBottomSheet;
```

with

```
_showModalBottomSheet();
```

---

And your `_showModalBottomSheet()` method should look like:

```
_showModalBottomSheet() {
  showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (_) => FlutterLogo(size: 56));
}
```

Comment: What if you want to close it automatically?

Comment: You can close it by using `Navigator.pop(context);`, don't forget to mark the answer accepted.

Comment: Future<void> requestPermission(Permission permission) async {
    final status = await permission.request();

    if(status != PermissionStatus.granted){
//      open AppSettings();
      _showModalBottomSheet(context);
    }else{
//     close modal bottom sheet;
      Navigator.pop(context);
      Position position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
      print(position.latitude);
      print(position.longitude);
      bloc.coordinate(position.latitude.toString() + position.longitude.toString());
    }
  }

Comment: You can ask it as a separate question by adding code details to it, I have provided you the answer to your current question, which you first accepted and then unaccepted.